# Foursquare authentication, passing a custom parameter

Tags: foursquare

Is there any way to pass a custom parameter to Foursquare that it will pass back in it's response?

In [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) you can pass custom parameters using the state parameter:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? 
  client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
  &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
  &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
  &state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING
```

The state parameter should be set to some arbitrary string you generate uniquely for each authentication request. This value will be passed back as a parameter to your redirect_uri once the user has authorized your app and you should check that the returned value matched the value you passed in at the start of the flow. This guards against Cross-site Request Forgery by ensuring the incoming redirect is part of the authentication flow which you initiated.

[Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) also has the state parameter:

state
any string
Indicates any state which may be useful to your application upon receipt of the response. The Google Authorization Server roundtrips this parameter, so your application receives the same value it sent. Possible uses include redirecting the user to the correct resource in your site, nonces, and cross-site-request-forgery mitigations.

It would be extremely helpful to have this using Foursquare as well.

Comment: It looks like you can pass the state parameter in Foursquare I will leave this question as reference as there is no mention of it in the Foursquare API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify additional URL parameters in your redirect_uri that are not part of the registered callback URL and they will be passed through upon successful authorization.

Comment: Would be great to see that in the documentation (dev.foursquare.com). I didn't see any mention of it.